# Ezdxf line quardinates

Tags: python, ezdxf

I want to get all coordinates of a line via ezdxf. I found nothing relevent. I am able to get only starting and ending points but I need all coordinates. Kindly guide.

Comment: Isn't a line just composed of starting and ending points?

Comment: yeah it is. but i need all coordinates i have to process the line by adding points on specific difference.

Comment: It would be better for you to interpolate and get the points you want manually. This could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25837544/8878627

Comment: tried this but not getting accurate results. by the way thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the start and the end points of a line segment, you do not need ezdxf to find the points on the line. You can use the Bresenham Algorithm, to get the other points.
Check out [Bresenham](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bresenhams-line-generation-algorithm/)